# How to properly print JSON in Twig templates?

Tags: javascript, twig

How to properly print JSON in Twig templates?

I am sending a array converted to JSON like that:

```
return $this->render('FrontBundle:Default:pipelinePlan.html.twig', array(
    'title' => 'Plan du pipeline',
    'markers' => json_encode($markers),
    'parcelles' => json_encode($parcelles),
    'parcellesInfos' => json_encode($parcellesInfos),
    'perimetre' => json_encode($perimetre),
    'pipeline' => json_encode($pipeline),
));
```

All JSON are working well, excepted one: "parcellesInfos"

When I print parcellesInfos the **"** characters are changed to **&quot**;

So I can't use **JSON.parse(parcellesInfos);**. Here is the error when I do that:

> pipeline-plan:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at
>   position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at initMap (pipeline-plan:828)
>       at js?

On PHP side, the JSON is correctly formatted, there are no unnecessary  **&quot** characters.

Why Twig is changing my **"** characters into **&quot** and how to prevent this?

If I add the "|raw" option to my variable, there is an error that is breaking the whole Javacript:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

**EDIT**

If I print my variable with raw option:

```
var parcelles = '{{parcelles|raw}}';
var parcellesInfos = '{{parcellesInfos|raw}}';
```

"parcelles" works well, but "parcellesInfos" is returning a different error depending on browser:

Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Firefox

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

This is how my json looks like after I do json_encode($parcellesInfos):

```
"{"495":{"no_fiche":"1","no_parcelle":"495","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"152.01 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Commune de Perly","adresse":"route de Certoux 51","np_localite":"1258 Perly","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant: Soldan Sylvain_ chemin des Mollex 45_ 1258 Perly. T\u00e9l: 079 683 75 91"},"496":{"no_fiche":"2","no_parcelle":"496","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"123.61 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Commune de Perly","adresse":"route de Certoux 51","np_localite":"1258 Perly","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant: Soldan Sylvain_ chemin des Mollex 45_ 1258 Perly. T\u00e9l: 079 683 75 91"},"467":{"no_fiche":"3","no_parcelle":"467","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"55.32 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"DAVID Elisabeth Madeleine Jeanne","adresse":"","np_localite":"","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"200":{"no_fiche":"4","no_parcelle":"200","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"49.19 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"CLAVEL Simone Marthe","adresse":"Route de Norcier 809","np_localite":"F-74160 Saint-.Julien-en Genevois","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant: Maigre Dominique_ rte de Soral 1233 Lully. T\u00e9l: 022 757 19 30"},"199":{"no_fiche":"5","no_parcelle":"199","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"83.47 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"MAGNIN Philippe","adresse":"Chemin de la L\u00e9chaire 47","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"962":{"no_fiche":"6","no_parcelle":"962","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"5.51 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Mairie de Perly-Certoux_ DP communal","adresse":"Rte de Certoux 51_ CP 150","np_localite":"1258 Perly","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"192":{"no_fiche":"7","no_parcelle":"192","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"25.37 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"MARTEL Pierre-Louis","adresse":"Avenue de Verniaz 4","np_localite":"F-74500 Evian-les-Bains","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Deque Dominique Ir\u00e8ne Marie-Jos\u00e9_ Pepin Marie-Jos\u00e8phe Charlotte_ Peronnet Fran\u00e7oise Ir\u00e8ne Marie-Keanne."},"191":{"no_fiche":"8","no_parcelle":"191","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"29.17 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Megevand Jeanne L\u00e9a","adresse":"Rue de Carouge 65","np_localite":"1205 Gen\u00e8ve","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Collombat Lucette Laure - Exploitant : Guilland Jean-Pierre_ Rte de Therens_ F-74160 Saint-Julien"},"190":{"no_fiche":"9","no_parcelle":"190","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"10.76 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Bocquet Claude","adresse":"Av. des Communes-R\u00e9unies 76","np_localite":"1258 Perly","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co.Prop. : Berthelier Christian Paul Roger_ Marchand Joseph_ Marchand Th\u00e9ophile_ Thalmann Roger Ernest_ Tremblet Louise Marguerite. "},"185":{"no_fiche":"10","no_parcelle":"185","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"47.03 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"SOCIETE IMMOBILIERE SUR LE CLOS c-o UGP","adresse":"C-O UGP SA_ Case postale 327","np_localite":"1211 Gen\u00e8ve 17","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Terrier Nicole_ route du Pr\u00e9-Marais_ Bernex. T\u00e9l: 022 757 57 32 - 079 436 91 12 Exploitant: Bouvier Xavier_ ch. Du village de Perly. T\u00e9l: 022 771 12 44 - 079 202 01 29"},"959":{"no_fiche":"11","no_parcelle":"959","commune":"PERLY-CERTOUX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"18.23 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"DP Cantonal - DGPN","adresse":"Rue des Battoirs 7","np_localite":"1205 Gen\u00e8ve","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Domaine Nature et Paysage_ Rue des battoirs 7_ 1205 Gen\u00e8ve"},"7670":{"no_fiche":"12","no_parcelle":"7670","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"32.00 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"DP Cantonal - DGPN","adresse":"Rue des Battoirs 7","np_localite":"1205 Gen\u00e8ve","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Domaine Nature et Paysage_ Rue des battoirs 7_ 1205 Gen\u00e8ve"},"1707":{"no_fiche":"13","no_parcelle":"1707","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"50.58 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"GASPARD Jeanne Maria","adresse":"Therens","np_localite":"F-74160 Therens","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Chevalley Marc_ Rte de Lo\u00ebx 157_ 1233 Bernex"},"7671":{"no_fiche":"14","no_parcelle":"7671","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"5.68 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Mairie de Bernex_ DP Communal","adresse":"Rue de Bernex 313","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"1690":{"no_fiche":"15","no_parcelle":"1690","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"26.66 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"CLAVEL Simone Marthe","adresse":"Route de Norcier 809","np_localite":"F-74160 Saint-.Julien-en Genevois","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant: Maigre Dominique_ rte de Soral 1233 Lully. T\u00e9l: 022 757 19 30"},"1689":{"no_fiche":"16","no_parcelle":"1689","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"34.46 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"SI ALFRED ANTHONIO c-o Fran\u00e7oise Weber","adresse":"Rue de Saint-Jean 3","np_localite":"1203 Gen\u00e8ve","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Tremblet Daniel_ Rte de Soral 106_ 1233 Lully"},"1688":{"no_fiche":"17","no_parcelle":"1688","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"17.12 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"DUVERNAY Patrick","adresse":"rte de Soral 144","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant: Niklaus Robert_ 142 route de Soral_ 1233 Bernex. T\u00e9l: 022 757 10 47"},"1868":{"no_fiche":"18","no_parcelle":"1868","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"17.19 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"NUSSBERGER Fabien","adresse":"553 route du Mandement","np_localite":"1283 Dardagny","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Patrick et Marc Favre_ Ch. des Grands-Buissons 13_ 1233 Bernex. T\u00e9l: 022 757 10 20"},"1867":{"no_fiche":"19","no_parcelle":"1867","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"18.77 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"HOTTELIER Aliz\u00e9e Marion","adresse":"Route des Chevaliers de Malte 15","np_localite":"1228 Plan-les-Ouates","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Hottelier Florence_ Hottelier Fr\u00e9d\u00e9rique Vriginie_ Hottelier G\u00e9rald Louis_ Hottelier Henri Jules_ Hottelier Thibaud Baptiste_ Trappier Monique Magali. Exploitant : Vidonne Claude_ La Gazonni\u00e8re S\u00e0rl_ Ch. des Marsins 19_ 1258 Perly + 41 chemin du Village 1258 Perly. t\u00e9l: 079 446 80 36"},"1686":{"no_fiche":"20","no_parcelle":"1686","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"24.84 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"TREMBLET Daniel","adresse":"Rte de Soral 106","np_localite":"1233 Lully","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"1866":{"no_fiche":"21","no_parcelle":"1866","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"36.12 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"HOTTELIER Aliz\u00e9e Marion","adresse":"Route des Chevaliers de Malte 15","np_localite":"1228 Plan-les-Ouates","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Hottelier Florence_ Hottelier Fr\u00e9d\u00e9rique Vriginie_ Hottelier G\u00e9rald Louis_ Hottelier Henri Jules_ Hottelier Thibaud Baptiste_ Trappier Monique Magali. Exploitant : Vidonne Claude_ La Gazonni\u00e8re S\u00e0rl_ Ch. des Marsins 19_ 1258 Perly + 41 chemin du Village 1258 Perly. t\u00e9l: 079 446 80 36"},"1864":{"no_fiche":"22","no_parcelle":"1864","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"25.64 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"GASPARD Jeanne Maria","adresse":"Therens","np_localite":"F-74160 Therens","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10572":{"no_fiche":"23","no_parcelle":"10572","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"7.07 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Mairie de Soral_ DP Communal","adresse":"Rte du Creux-de-Boisset 23","np_localite":"1286 Soral","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10023":{"no_fiche":"24","no_parcelle":"10023","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"11.18 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Megevand Jeanne L\u00e9a","adresse":"Rue de Carouge 65","np_localite":"1205 gen\u00e8ve","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Collombat Lucette Laure - Exploitant : Guilland Jean-Pierre_ Rte de Therens_ F-74160 Saint-Julien"},"10022":{"no_fiche":"25","no_parcelle":"10022","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"70.82 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"GUILLAND Claude Gilles Marcel","adresse":"Rte de Therens 701","np_localite":"F-74160 Saint-.Julien-en Genevois","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Guilland Jean Pierre Charles"},"10021":{"no_fiche":"26","no_parcelle":"10021","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901","long_tube":"28.63 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"HOMINAL Antonia Maria","adresse":"Rte de Therens 803","np_localite":"F-74160 Saint-.Julien-en Genevois","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Hominal Marie-Ang\u00e9le Eug\u00e9nie"},"10020":{"no_fiche":"27","no_parcelle":"10020","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1901-1902","long_tube":"24.31 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"DUPRAZ John Fran\u00e7ois","adresse":"Rue du Faubourg 13","np_localite":"1286 Soral","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10570":{"no_fiche":"28","no_parcelle":"10570","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"10.95 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Mairie de Soral_ DP Communal","adresse":"Rte du Creux-de-Boisset 23","np_localite":"1286 Soral","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10012":{"no_fiche":"29","no_parcelle":"10012","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"73.92 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"COMPAGNON Paul","adresse":"Ch. Laconnex 141","np_localite":"F-74160 Saint-.Julien-en Genevois","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10011":{"no_fiche":"30","no_parcelle":"10011","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"40.58 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"BOYMOND Jean-Pierre","adresse":"Av. Tr\u00e9sum 12","np_localite":"F-74000 Annecy","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Boymond Gabriel"},"10010":{"no_fiche":"31","no_parcelle":"10010","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"91.40 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"BOCQUET Georgette","adresse":"Rue Louis-Martel 23","np_localite":"F-74160 Saint-.Julien-en Genevois","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant: Fontaine Philippe_ ch.du Bois-de-By 16_ 1286 Soral. T\u00e9l - 079 649 29 41"},"10568":{"no_fiche":"32","no_parcelle":"10568","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"10.60 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Mairie de Soral_ DP Communal","adresse":"Rte du Creux-de-Boisset 23","np_localite":"1286 Soral","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10001":{"no_fiche":"33","no_parcelle":"10001","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"189.31 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"BOUVIER Xavier Pierre Adolphe","adresse":"Ch. du Village-de-Perly","np_localite":"1258 Perly","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10567":{"no_fiche":"34","no_parcelle":"10567","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"11.09 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Mairie de Soral_ DP Communal","adresse":"Rte du Creux-de-Boisset 23","np_localite":"1286 Soral","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10049":{"no_fiche":"35","no_parcelle":"10049","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"123.83 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"BARBIER Marie Madeleine Th\u00e9r\u00e8se","adresse":"route de Soral 301","np_localite":"1286 Soral","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10048":{"no_fiche":"36","no_parcelle":"10048","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"51.08 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"MAIGRE Dominique Pierre","adresse":"Rte de Soral 99","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10047":{"no_fiche":"37","no_parcelle":"10047","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"49.23 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"CLAVEL Lucien Joseph Fran\u00e7ois","adresse":"Rte de Norcier 809","np_localite":"F-74160 Saint-.Julien-en Genevois","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co-Prop. : Clavel Simoine_ Clavel Jean-Pierre_ Clavel Marie-No\u00eblle Ex: Maigre Dominique_ rte de Soral 1233 Lully. T\u00e9l: 022 757 19 30"},"10046":{"no_fiche":"38","no_parcelle":"10046","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"48.36 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"YERLY Olivier Pierre","adresse":"Ch. de Chavanay 9","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10061":{"no_fiche":"39","no_parcelle":"10061","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"38.94 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"GUILLAND Lucette Ren\u00e9e","adresse":"Rte de Therens","np_localite":"F-74160 Saint-.Julien-en Genevois","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Guilland Jean-Pierre et Claude_ Rte de Therens_ F-74160 Saint-Julien-en-Genevois"},"10578":{"no_fiche":"40","no_parcelle":"10578","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"13.18 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Mairie de Soral_ DP Communal","adresse":"Rte du Creux-de-Boisset 23","np_localite":"1286 Soral","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10045":{"no_fiche":"41","no_parcelle":"10045","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902","long_tube":"6.94 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"YERLY Olivier Pierre","adresse":"Ch. de Chavanay 9","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10044":{"no_fiche":"42","no_parcelle":"10044","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1902-1903","long_tube":"46.55 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"YERLY Olivier Pierre","adresse":"Ch. de Chavanay 9","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10043":{"no_fiche":"43","no_parcelle":"10043","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"30.52 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"CHARRIERE Bernard Georges","adresse":"Ch. des Curiades 4","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"10081":{"no_fiche":"44","no_parcelle":"10081","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"138.79 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"MEYER Claude Andr\u00e9 Camille","adresse":"Rte de Forestal 53","np_localite":"1285 Athenaz","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Pierre et Paysages SA_ chemin du Loup 30_ 1233 Bernex. T\u00e9l: 022 757 68 37"},"10080":{"no_fiche":"45","no_parcelle":"10080","commune":"SORAL","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"13.88 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"DETHURENS Solange","adresse":"Rue Jeantet 2","np_localite":"F-01200 Bellegarde s-Valserine","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"7661":{"no_fiche":"46","no_parcelle":"7661","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"8.29 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"Mairie de Bernex_ DP Communal ","adresse":"Rue de Bernex 313","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"1566":{"no_fiche":"47","no_parcelle":"1566","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"49.43 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"DUPRAZ Claude Christophe Hubert","adresse":"Av. de Miremont 27b","np_localite":"1206 Gen\u00e8ve","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"1565":{"no_fiche":"48","no_parcelle":"1565","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"27.49 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"CHARRIERE Jean Alfred","adresse":"Rte de Soral 124d","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":""},"7660":{"no_fiche":"49","no_parcelle":"7660","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"13.50 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"DP Cantonal","adresse":"Ch. Des Oliquettes 4","np_localite":"1213 Petit-Lancy 1","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant: DGGC"},"566":{"no_fiche":"50","no_parcelle":"566","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"41.03 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"FAVRE Marc","adresse":"Ch. des Grands-Buissons 13","np_localite":"1233 Bernex","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Co. Prop. : Favre Patrick"},"565":{"no_fiche":"51","no_parcelle":"565","commune":"BERNEX","no_servitude":"","no_plan_sappro":"1903","long_tube":"19.42 m","version":"2015","proprietaire":"GIRARD Jacqueline Rose","adresse":"Rte de Saint-Julien 289c","np_localite":"1258 Perly","tel":"","mail":"","remarques":"Exploitant : Magnin Philippe_ Ch. de la L\u00e9chaire 47_ 1233 Bernex t\u00e9l: 022 757 26 84"}}
```

**EDIT 2**

Look at @MrCode answer, I changed this:

```
var parcellesInfos = '{{parcellesInfos|raw}}';
parcellesInfos = JSON.parse(parcellesInfos);
```

Into

```
var parcellesInfos = {{parcellesInfos|raw}};
```

It worked perfectly!! :)

Now I wonder why all other JSON were working, and only this one was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes because your variable is JSON which is valid JavaScript, so you can simply do:

```
var parcelles = {{parcelles|raw}};
var parcellesInfos = {{parcellesInfos|raw}};
```

There is also no need to try to JSON decode it.

The JSON that was having the error has probably got a single quote in its data. The single quote would terminate your variable prematurely and cause the syntax error.

Comment: Indeed the JSON that was having the error has surely a single quote in it.

Comment: This is stupid way to do it. Just send the data without encoding it to json and use twig to display it as json.

Answer (score 0):

```
var parcelles = {{parcelles|json_encode()}};
```

Comment: Can you please add an explanation to  your code snippet?